# Is there an equation for the acceleration of gravity in a disk of uniform density?

Tags: gravity

I tried to solve this problem by entering this monster of an equation into Wolfram:
$$G\rho\left(\int_{-R}^{2r-1}2\int_{0}^{\sqrt{R^{2}-x^{2}}}\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{\left(x-r\right)^{2}+y^{2}}^{3}}dydx+\int_{-2r-1}^{R}2\int_{\sqrt{\left(1-r\right)^{2}-\left(x-r\right)^{2}}}^{\sqrt{R^{2}-x^{2}}}\frac{x-r}{\sqrt{\left(x-r\right)^{2}+y^{2}}^{3}}dydx\right)$$

where $G$ is the gravitational constant, $\rho$ is the disk's density, measured in kilograms per square meter, $R$ is its radius, $r$ is the distance from the center, and $x$ and $y$ are position values inside the disk. The thickness of the disk is negligible. It didn't give a result. Is there a simple equation, or is it as nasty as you'd expect the result of an integral like this to be?

Comment: Why not just use cylindrical coordinates? Also without any background work it's hard to tell if your integral is even correct. If you've seen the derivation for the electric field of a thin disk, the formula is almost exactly the same but with the appropriate constants changed out